# Power BI DAX formula for dynamic percentages with filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, percentage

I am new to Power BI and trying to create a simple card with percentages that will change when I select each category on my slicer. I need the nominator AND denominator to change with each filter - trying to achieve the '**% of column total**' function in Excel, but on this visual. This is a measure I created to calculate % of leavers over active, but it is not dynamic.

`CALCULATE(COUNTA('Leaver'[ID]), /counta('Active'[ID])`

My slicer has 3 regions: Central, Southern, Eastern. When filtered by Central, I need the card to show count of leavers from Central region out of total population in Central region. Currently the filter is working but the denominator pool is constant.

Comment: Add some sample data because currently, we don't know how your data are related. Your regions are in Leaver/Active table?  Don't use COUNTA! This is bad for performance.

Comment: I will try and share some sample data. My interface is indeed very slow at the moment.. I use several measures that require COUNTA to get the count of unique ID's from the ID integer column. What could be a substitute?

Comment: this one: COUNTROWS( VALUES('Leaver'[ID])); 

And full measure may looks like (but it depend on your sample data/ model relationship):

measure = 
var __xx = SELECTEDVALUE('RegionForSlicer'[Region])

CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( VALUES('Leaver'[ID])) , ALLSELECTED( 'Leaver'[Region]),  'Leaver'[Region] = __xx  )